# Nokia Lumia 920 no signal

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

My mom's 920 ran out of juice and turned off. She then charged it and now the phone no longer recognizes the SIM. It just says No Service. Tried everything, reset the phone to factory setting, not in airplane mode. After about a week, it showed the signal, but call couldn't be completed.

I have SIM unlocked the phone. My mom was using it for the past 4 months in Nepal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried another SIM card in the phone?

Answer (score -1):

If it was purchased in a different country you may want to check the network settings and compare it to what should work with your provider.  Also note that most companies will have a number of configurations and you might need to go through trying different configs until you get it working.